# Proof: $\Bbb{Z}$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I must proof the following:

"$ \Bbb{Z}$ is not bounded"

with $\Bbb{Z} \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, and $\Bbb{R} $ is complete ordered field.

I thought, by contraddiction, if $ \Bbb{Z}$ is bounded then $ \Bbb{Z} $ is bounded belove and bounded above, but if $\Bbb{Z} $ is bounded above then also $\Bbb{N} $ is bounded above and it is an absurd; if $\Bbb{Z}$ is bounded belove then $ \exists t \in \Bbb{R}(\forall x \in \Bbb{Z}(t \leq x))$ and $t+1$ is not lower bound of $\Bbb{Z}$ therefore $\exists r \in \Bbb{Z}(r<t+1)$, and $ \Bbb{Z} \ni r-1<t $ but by hypothesis then $t \leq r-1$ and $t>r-1$, therefore $ t \leq r-1 \wedge t\geq r-1 \wedge t \neq r-1$ and $ t=r-1 \wedge t\neq r-1$, and it is an absurd!

Is it correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The proof should start like this (for not bounded above). Suppose to the contrary $\mathbb{Z}$ is bounded above. Let $b$ be the least upper bound. Continue.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, if $b$ is upper bound then $\forall x \in \Bbb{Z}(x \leq b)$, but $b-1$ is not upper bound of $\Bbb{Z}$ then $\exists y \in \Bbb{Z}(b-1<y)$ and also $b<y+1 \in \Bbb{Z}$ but by hypothesis I have $y+1\leq b$ and $b<y+1$ therefore $b=y+1 \wedge b\neq y+1$, and It is an absurd? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's basically fine. You could and should have stopped at $y+1\le b$ and $b\lt y+1$, this is impossible since we cannot have $y+1\lt y+1$. It would be preferable, I think, to use more words and fewer logical symbols.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks soo much! :) Thanks for hint! :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z$ being bounded implies $\Bbb Z$ being bounded above, which in turn implies that $\Bbb N$ is bounded above, contradicting the Archimedean Property of the Reals, then you don't even need to consider whether or not $\Bbb Z$ has a lower bound.

If you wish to prove that $\Bbb Z$ has neither an upper bound *nor* a lower bound in $\Bbb R,$ then it is perhaps simpler to observe that if $t$ is a lower bound of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb R,$ then $-t$ is an upper bound of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb R$ (why?) and so is an upper bound of $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb R.$ So, we need only show/know that $\Bbb N$ has no upper bound in $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Pretty sure the point of the question is to prove the Archimedean property.

Comment: @Andres: Perhaps so, but looking at the proof offered by the OP showing that $\Bbb Z$ has no lower bound, I suspect that the OP has already seen a proof that $\Bbb N$ has no upper bound in $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

Let a∈R.

Let K∈R>0.

By the Archimedean Principle there exists n∈N such that n>a+K.

As N⊆Z: ∃n∈Z:a+K$<$n

And so: n∉BK(a)

As this applies whatever a and K are, it follows that there is no BK(a) which contains all the integers.

Hence the result, by definition of bounded space.