# About equivalent form of Archimedean property and Archimedean principle

Tags: real-analysis

I studied the following property in real analysis:

- ***(1) Archimedean property***: let be $\Bbb{R}$ a complete ordered field, then $$\forall x \in \Bbb{R}(\exists t \in \Bbb{Z}(x < t))$$
- ***Proof (1):*** by contradiction, I have $$ \exists x \in \Bbb{R}(\forall t \in \Bbb{Z}(t\leq x))$$ but $\Bbb{Z}$ [is not bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674135/proof-bbbz-is-not-bounded)
- ***(2) Archimedean principle***: let be $\Bbb{R}$ a complete ordered field, then $$\forall x\in \Bbb{R}^+,y \in \Bbb{R}(\exists t \in \Bbb{Z}(tx > y))$$
- ***Proof (2):*** by contradiction, I have $$\exists x\in \Bbb{R}^+,y \in \Bbb{R}(\forall t \in \Bbb{Z}(tx \leq y))$$ but $x \neq 0$ therefore $t \leq \frac{x}{y}$, but $\Bbb{Z}$[is not bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674135/proof-bbbz-is-not-bounded)

Is Archimedean property equivalent to $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}(\exists t \in \Bbb{Z}(t<x ))$?

Is Archimedean principle equivalent to $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}^+,y \in \Bbb{R}(\exists t \in \Bbb{Z}(y>tx))$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for the Archimedean property.

About the Archimedean "principle", I think I see what you mean but you wrote twice the same thing. I think if you want to change the sign of the inequation, you need to define x as negative to get the equivalent. Otherwise just take $x=1$ and $y=0.5$, there is no solution.

Comment: oh sorry... I edited my post, Is it correct?

Comment: Yes ! simply apply each of the versions to $-y$ and you get the existence of the $t$ ($-t$ is probably the best candidate)